# Enviar dados junto com formulario

Tags: html

Complementando minha duvida anterior (goo.gl/rNMK7c) e eu quiser que ao clicar no botão pra preencher o formulário o código pegue qual produto o cliente se interessou, pois vai ter um botão pra cada item, qdo o cliente clicar no botão que na imagem esta como contato seja informado no formulário qual item ele se interessou, onde estão as flechas, tem como fazer sem php, não estudei ainda, conheço pouco, segue print do site que estou fazendo prntscr.com/ghgf8p

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('#id').val($(this).attr('data-id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="ID">
   <input type="text" placeholder="nome">
</form>

<button data-id="1">Primeiro item</button>
<button data-id="2">Segundo item</button>
```

Nao deu pra entender muito sua duvida, mas acredito que seja algo assim.

Comment: Rafael Augusto desculpe a ignorancia, mas onde coloco esse código, ao clicar no botão tem que abrir um formulario onde o cliente vai inserir seus dados e enviar, e precisará ser enviado por email. Vou colocar como estão os codigos:

Comment: Botão: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('form.html', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=YES, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=YES, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=90%, LEFT=280%, WIDTH=485, HEIGHT=545');"><img src='imagens/button-contato.png'></a>

Comment: form.html 
<!-- Do not change the code! -->
<a id="foxyform_embed_link_181315" href="http://br.foxyform.com/">foxyform</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, t){
        var g = d.createElement(t),
                s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src = "http://br.foxyform.com/js.php?id=181315&sec_hash=e727220c0f2&width=445px&heigth=525px";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    }(document, "script"));
</script>
<!-- Do not change the code! -->
</body>
</html>

Comment: Provavelmente precisarei trocar esse formulário, pois já peguei um tipo plugin pronto.